# replace null with 0 for the returned from count(*) function of aggregator in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using aggregator transformation in my Informatica mapping where I am counting number of records coming from sql override.I need to pass zero value to target table as counts in case if I get 0 number of return counts from count(*) function of Aggregator Transformation.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that count in SQL Override and use NVL or ZEROIFNULL there only to return the count or zero because if your SQL override doesn't returns anything Informatica transformations will not get initiated and you'll get Null in place of zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do someting like this:

count(IIF(isnull(AGG_PORT),0,AGG_PORT))

That should do it.